# Exception No form element was specified for "title" and one not be determined automatically from "Spiffy\Zend\Form"

Tags: validation, zend-framework, annotations, doctrine-orm

In addtion to my previous question [Attache zend filters and validation chains to models/doctrine entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10195188/attache-zend-filters-and-validation-chains-to-models-doctrine-entities) I have given a try to Spiffy framework, but I got stack with this exception like this: Exception No form element was specified for "title" and one not be determined automatically from "Spiffy\Zend\Form".
In my entity I  have this:

```
<?php

namespace Entities;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Spiffy\Doctrine\AbstractEntity as Entity;
use Spiffy\Doctrine\Annotations\Filters as Filter;
use Spiffy\Doctrine\Annotations\Validators as Assert;

/** @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Repositories\PostRepository") */
class Post extends Entity {

public function __construct()     
{
    $this->created  = new \DateTime("now");
    $this->comments = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}


public function __get($property)
{
    return $this->$property;
}

public function __set($name, $value)
{
    $this->$name = $value;

    return $this->$name;
}

/**
 * @ORM\Id @ORM\Column(type="integer") @ORM\GeneratedValue
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string $title
 * @Filter\Alnum
 * @Assert\StringLength(5)
 * @ORM\Column(type="string",length=255) 
 */
private $title;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text")
 */
private $body;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 */
private $created;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Comment", mappedBy="post", fetch="LAZY")
 */
private $comments;
}
```

And my form is like this:

```
   <?php
   use \Spiffy\Zend\Form as Form;
   class Application_Form_Post extends Form
   {

     public function init()
    {

      //var_dump($this->getEntity()); //returns null
      // die;
      $this->add('title');

      $this->add('body');

     $this->addElement('submit', 'submit', array(

    ));

  }
 }
```

So I am block myself here. Thank you for your help.

Comment: After I added also this method to my form,  public function getDefaultOptions() 
            {
                return array('entity' => 'Entities\Post');
            } and a couple of debugging of the error messages, I reach to another exception: Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver does not exist'

Comment: I have two zend resources: one from Bisna and the other from Spiffy: Spiffy/Zend/Application/Resource. If I put in my application.ini Spiffy resource, the second one, then I got the reflectionException, but if I put on the second position the bisna resource, then when I try to display my form, I got the xeception: No entry is registered for key 'Spiffy_Doctrine' Any help? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to completely disable the Bisna resource? Otherwise you're probably even using 2 different EntityManagers...

Answer (score 0):

In my application.ini, I comented out this lines:

```
 pluginPaths.Bisna\Application\Resource\ = "Bisna/Application/Resource"
```

and

```
autoloaderNamespaces[] = Bisna
```

but I still got the exception:

```
  Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver does not exist' in C:\Spiffy\lib\Spiffy\Doctrine\Container.php on line 359
```

What is not clear for me, is that in the bisna resource I had something like this:

```
  \Zend_Registry::set('doctrine', $container);
```

and in the spiffy resource I had like this:

```
 `Zend_Registry::set('Spiffy_Doctrine', $container);`
```

But in my Boostrap.php, I had this two:

```
    $this->bootstrap('doctrine');
    $container = $this->getResource('doctrine');
```

I was expected to be a diffrence between doctrine and Spiffy_Doctrine, but is not. And something else that is for me, not understandable. I modify some line in Spiffy container like this:

```
try{
$reflClass = new ReflectionClass($driverClass);
}catch (LogicException $Exception) {
die('Not gonna make it in here...');
}
catch(ReflectionException $Exception)
{
die('Your class does not exist! ' );
}
```

but instead of cacthing the exception, I got this:

```
`Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException'`
```

Ps: Sorry for the duplication of content from the doctrine group from linekdin, but these are my answers.  Rigth now I debug my application, maybe I will figure out what I'm missing, but any help will be great. Thank you.

Comment: I was debuggin, but I still don't know what I'm missing.

Comment: After two days, of looking into the code, debugging, mostly with var_dump, echo, and die, even I have a debugger, I kind of making work( a little manual hacking) but just for a special situation. It works very well for Filters, I only tested just two, but I guess it's ok for all, and for at last one validator that I try it myself. First I choose the bisna, and for the Spiffy resource I have changed in the registry Spiffy_Doctrine with doctrine, in order to use bisna entitymanager. Then I elminate the default validator for the string type, I add two public fileds for the annotation StringLength

Comment: : min and max, in order to be able to generate Zend_Validate_StringLength($min.$max) validator from my title property of my entity: /**
     * @var string $title
     * @Filter\Alnum
     * @Filter\StripTags
     * @Assert\StringLength(min=8,max=12)
     * @ORM\Column(type="string",length=12) 
     */
    private $title;

Comment: Now it works, for my particular case, but of course I should, add for every annotation, some defaults values, like $min and $max for StringLength, and I not even a message, to have somtehing like this in my entity: @Assert\StringLength(min=8,max=12,message='You may enter only from 8 to 12 alpanumeric characters). The idea is that when I define my validation annotation like above, to send an array of options to the coresponding validator class from zend framework. It requires some work to have some very flexible annotation and of course based on those the appropriate validator.

Comment: I, of course could use filters and validators at the level of form itself, and not generated from the model(doctrine 2 entities), but I think that I have filters and validators at the model level, then using those entities inside of service layer which may provide it's services to either: the controller in an web context by using maybe the form, or to some kind of other context or web service.